# ffmpeg mp4 cut from correct point | without encode

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using this this command for cut my mp4 video :

```
ffmpeg -i clip.mp4 -ss 00:00:25 -to 00:01:20 -c copy cutted.mp4
```

But there is a problem with this code. My "cutted" clip has black video for a couple seconds and it's have sync problem on editing software. When i tweak the first parameter -ss like 00:00:24 ... 00:00:23 .... 00:00:26 etc when i found the right position it doesn't have any black frame or sync problem. I want to learn how can i learn all of this correct times for my video ? I don't know what should i call these points. Gop or anything else. Is there any solution built-in ffmpeg to learn this times so i can cut them without any corruption ? Thanks!

Comment: Try moving your `-ss 00:00:25` to before the `-i`... `ffmpeg -i clip.mp4 -to 00:01:20 -c copy cutted.mp4`

Comment: @UltrasoundJelly Thank you soo much. It's working perfectly! You can write it as a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `-ss 00:00:25` to before the `-i` Here it is in your example:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:25 -i clip.mp4 -t 55 -c copy cutted.mp4
```

This moves `-ss` from an *output* option, which will "seek to the closest seek point before your time," to an *input* option, which "decodes but discards input until the timestamps reach [your] position."  Input option is much more accurate in my experience.  More details [here](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html). `-t` denotes time of output clip in seconds.